# PHP: form with multiple checkboxes with the same variable name: which keys are set in the resulting array?

Tags: php

Let's say we have the typical HTML form with multiple checkboxes with the same variable name, to be sent to a PHP script:

```
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME=camino[0] VALUE=1>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME=camino[1] VALUE=66>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME=camino[2] VALUE=77>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME=camino[3] VALUE=67>
```

If only some of the checkboxes are marked, how does the resulting array show up in PHP? I would have thought that only the marked variable would be set; in other words, that the resulting array would be something like:

```
Array (
 [2] => 77
 )
```

But sometimes the array I get as a result does have all the keys set, and only the unmarked values are set as null:

```
Array (
 [0] =>
 [1] =>
 [2] => 77
 [3] => 
 )
```

I have a local PHP 5.4.45 installation where the first thing happens, and another test server with 5.4.16 where the second thing happens. Which is the "correct" behaviour? Does it depend on a INI setting somewhere?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you show us the code you used in PHP?

Comment: Sorry, the code was really convoluted, a mess of libraries stacked inside one another and not very well written. Anyway, I finally managed to debug it in a different way. Maybe i should close this question?

Comment: Yes, you can delete the question if the problem is no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_filter

```
$array = array(
                            0 => 1,
                            1 => 0,
                            2 => 1,
                            3 => 0);
var_dump($array);
echo "<br>";

// Filtering the array
$result = array_filter($array);
var_dump($result);
```

output:

> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [2]=> int(1) }